# Unrecognized name 'column' when using _TABLE_SUFFIX in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following BigQuery dataset:

A set of tables with name `keywords_ab`, `keywords_ac`, ..., `keywords_zz`.

Another set of tables with name `keywords_different_schema_ab`, `keywords_different_schema_ac`,...

These two set of tables have a different schema. I would like to run a query on the first set of tables, which contain a column named `term` which is not contained in `keywords_different_schema_*` instead.

I was normally running these kind of queries using the syntax `FROM 'keywords_*'` but this is giving me a `Unrecognized name 'term'` of course because the `term` column is not part of all the `keywords_different_schema_*` tables.

I have also tried to put in my query something like `LENGTH(_TABLE_SUFFIX) = 2` but it seems not  to work fine.
Is there a way to have the wildcard working for this case? Or should I really do a `UNION` selecting manually all the keywords I am interested in ?

Comment: Ah, tricky! Can you move the one set of tables into another dataset, or easily rename them? This would obviously make things easier. If not, then use a union would be the best approach.

Comment: Unfortunately they need to stay in the same dataset. I will rename the 2nd set if there is no other option, but the preference would be to keep the name as they are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there is a way to solve this problem without having to rename the tables (even though it's quite a hacky way).

Apparently, BigQuery is looking at the last table you created that matches the wildcard.

What I did was to create a new table called `keywords_dummy` and giving them the UNION of all `keywords` and `keywords_different_schema` attributes.

At that point, my query `SELECT term FROM 'keywords_*' WHERE LENGTH(_table_suffix)=2` worked since BigQuery was checking this `keywords_dummy` table that has the `term` column.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `WHERE` clause to your query to exclude any data from tables that you are forced into selecting, for example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 'keywords_*
WHERE _table_suffix NOT LIKE "%_different_schema_%"
```

This will exclude any table where the suffix contains the text `_different_schema_` anywhere in the name.

Your queries will be more expensive because you are scanning all the data, a better longer term solution would be to rename them and keep this in mind for next time, thinking ahead if you know you'll want to query these tables with wildcards - something I have been caught out by too!

Comment: this is not working for me either (I guess is the same as the `WHERE LENGTH(_TABLE_SUFFIX) = 2` I have put in the question ), I will probably have to just rename the tables at this point

Comment: How is it not working? Are you still getting results from the `keywords_different_schema_ab` table in results?

Comment: I keep getting the `Unrecognized name 'term'` error, so I can't even do the query.

Comment: oh ok, it's because in your example you are doing a `select *` . That one would work, but what I would need to do is to select just a few columns among which I have columns not present in the other tables, not doing a `select *`

Comment: Okay, I don't see why you couldn't do that? Can you share a full example of your code?

Comment: Sure. So, in my example the `term` column is part of only the `keywords_ab`, etc.. and  I am doing a `SELECT term FROM 'keywords_*' WHERE _table_suffix NOT LIKE '%_different_schema_%'` and BigQuery is returning me a `Unrecognized name: term`

Comment: I think BigQuery is taking the schema from the first field it finds, looks like renaming might be your only option here!